# How to get statistics for selenium grid utilization

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I'm using selenium grid with 13 nodes, each one is limited to one chrome instance.
My project uses most of those nodes on different times.

In the future, I will need to add more nodes - due to more tests, parallel exec., different browsers , etc.
The problem is that I can't tell exactly what is the utilization of the grid's nodes.

is there a way to get the following statistics from the grid:

1. nodes idle / busy time in % - determine if the node was busy most of the time or idle most of the time
2. amount of executed test since the node was started
3. running time - duration since the node was started

thanks
Tizki

Comment: you could try to use the chrome feature (Win:F12, Mac:Alt+CMD+I ) and check if there is something helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a Servlet on the hub so that you can check those statistics directly from a browser just by loading the URL. Check the class **RegistryBasedServlet**.

Then on the node's launch script you will launch that node directly from a launcher java class that contains a loop that collects all the information you neeed on that node.

You could also use that loop to update that node configuration and re-register on the hub.

Then from the servlet, you may process all node and collect all the information. From the hub's registry and/or the servlet.